# Returning double.NaN in my custom function: is it a good practice?

Tags: c#, floating-point, nan

(There is a kinda similar question about returning NaN but it does not answer this)

I'm a beginner coder (therefore always unsure about what is a good practice) and I'm writing a method that calculates the direction angle of some object moving in 2d space (it's for a Codingame challenge). For this, I wrote a method

```
public static double GetAngle(double deltaX, double deltaY)
{
    if (deltaX==0 && deltaY==0) return double.NaN; //if not moving the direction is undefined
    //...
    //calculations etc
    return result;
}
```

Is it a good practice to return a NaN like that? Seems convenient and logical (the object does not move, hence no speed, hence no speed vector), but somehow I feel that it could lead to some hard to discover bugs later when this method is used in other calculations (of course I will use a NaN check where I remember but still). If necessary, this method could return 0 instead of NaN and I could live with that.

Comment: You could use something similar to the NET `TryParse` methods and return a bool

Comment: Thanks, I'll read about that. Though I am thinking a function should not return two different types depending on conditions (if I understood you right).

Comment: **[Int32.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)**  Microsoft thinks it is ok

Comment: I must've misunderstood, I thought you meant for me to put a TryParse in my function's return statement so it would normally return a double and sometimes a boolean.

Comment: No, more like use that as a pattern: `bool TryGetAngle(double X, double Y, out double angle)`

Comment: Ah. That's a neat construction, I'll consider it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

While in some ways it's logical, I'd suggest that a more idiomatic approach would be to use a `Nullable<double>`, also written as `double?`:

```
public static double? GetAngle(double deltaX, double deltaY)
{
    if (deltaX == 0 && deltaY == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    // ...
    // Calculations etc
    return result;
}
```

That's likely to be more consistent with how you express "non-results" for other code.

Aside from anything else, the fact that the return type is `double?` rather than `double` will force callers to think about the no-result option - whereas it's very easy to call a method that returns NaN and end up propagating that NaN value elsewhere accidentally.

Comment: "Aside from anything else" => probably THE reason to use it this way,

Comment: Oh! I didn't think about it that way. I read that doubles are not nullable before so I thought I should use NaN (which, I thought, is sort of a null replacement for this stuff). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I often return null if no result is found, and stick to always using null. If you cant return null here then use double.NaN

Comment: Thanks, that was my intention before I learned about non-nullable types. I think that double? from Daisy Shipton's recommendation would work ideally here.